# Proving (or disproving) that these maps are linear representations

Tags: representation-theory

I am working in $V = C(\mathbb{R})$, the complex vector space of continuous $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$. I have the following series of maps $\rho : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow GL(V)$ defined as:

1. $\rho(t) : f(x) \mapsto f(x-t)$
2. $\rho(t) : f(x) \mapsto f(tx)$
3. $\rho(t) : f(x) \mapsto f(e^tx)$
4. $\rho(t) : f(x) \mapsto e^t f(x)$

I must determine which of these maps define a linear representation of the additive group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$. From Serre, I am given the following definition to work with: $\rho(st) = \rho(s) \rho(t)$ where $s,t \in G$. So, I just need to determine which of these maps satisfy this definition - which seems like a routine task, but I'm getting stuck in how to proceed. Perhaps I am getting too tangled up in the notation, but I'm having a hard time with what I need to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be confused by the fact that your definition $\rho(st)=\rho(s)\rho(t)$ uses multiplicative notation and you want to apply it to the additive group $(\mathbb R,+)$. In additive notation, this is $\rho(s+t)=\rho(s)\rho(t)$.

I’ll do the first two and leave the other two for you.

$$
\rho(s+t)(f)(x)=f(x-(s+t))\;,\\\rho(t)(f)(x)=f(x-t)\;,\\\rho(s)\rho(t)(f)(x)=f((x-s)-t)\;,
$$

so indeed $\rho(s+t)=\rho(s)\rho(t)$.

$$
\rho(s+t)(f)(x)=f((s+t)x)\;,\\\rho(t)(f)(x)=f(tx)\;,\\\rho(s)\rho(t)(f)(x)=f(t(sx))\;,
$$

and in general $f((s+t)x)\neq f(tsx)$, so this one is not a representation of the additive group. (In fact, it’s a representation of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb R^*,\cdot)$.)